# For loop for subfolders and flat folders at once

Tags: bash, for

I use this code in my scripts to process files inside a folder, but it only works for subfolders.

```
if [ -d "$1" ]; then for file in "${1%/}/"*/*(*.mkv|*.mp4|*.avi); do
```

I know I can just remove `/*` to work with flat folders, but I'm looking for a more clean way to handle both flat folders ( no subfolders ) and folders with  subfolders.

I have big code in the for loop so I don't want solutions that rely on `find`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `globstar` and `extglob` which is specific to `bash`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar extglob

if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
  for file in "$1"/**/*.@(mkv|mp4|avi); do
  :
  done
fi
```

Comment: `extglob` enable it and use `bash`

Comment: try now, the `*.@` seems to work, it was `*@.` that before.

Comment: Line 9 says `fi`, how did you get that error message?

Comment: @Freedo It would work if the website ran your code on a directory with files matching. When you run `bash` code on  some website like that, the code is not actually running on _your_ machine.  Your browser just sends the code off, it gets executed, and their web server sends the output back. It would be better if you tested your code on your own machine, in a terminal.

Comment: Working now, I don't know what happened earlier I changed it to see if it'd work... but anyway thanks!! Brilliant answer. You can delete the old comments

Comment: What if I want to match only specific filenames? like match `test.srt` but not `something.srt`

Comment: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Comment: Got it thanks. Just needed to replace the `*.` before `@` with some pattern or even harcoded value...

Answer (score 1):

> I have big code in the for loop so I don't want solutions that rely on `find`

If you change the `for` loop to a `while` loop and use `read`, it's easy to rely on `find` without further refactoring of what's inside the loop:

```
find "$1" -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.avi" -print0 | \
while read -d '' file; do
  # Process file
done
```